# Terminated for pace and production, despite compliments of improvement from supervisors

Tags: termination

I was working at a warehouse for one month.  I came in with a learning attitude, I was asking questions and getting tips to improve. The performance they wanted was to pick 26 boxes every 5 minutes. I would fluctuate between 21 to 29 boxes every 5 minutes.

This varies due to other factors, such as *malfunctioning machines*, *slower co-workers*, *not enough caddies for everyone*, *and fluctuating workloads* **(despite best attempts to always keep moving)**.  I also never had reliability issues, I always arrived on time and never had attitude problems.

Edit: I also remembered that other co-workers would take my caddies, if I were to slow for them or they needed work to find.

I also noticed that the indeed reviews mentioned similar problems I experienced. People would do their best, but only get terminated for pace and productivity.  Despite the fact that employees with seniority worked slower and did not get terminated.

Questions

- Where should I begin to prevent something like this from happening
  again?
- What can I learn from this experience?
- Was I really a bad employee? Was I a lazy worker?

Comment: Was this at Amazon?

Comment: @JMERICKS Let's just call it warehouse. I don't feel comfortable sharing the name of the company I worked for.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I could reflect back to the last day of work. I remember someone getting hurt, and productivity took a hit.   They brought other people from another department, these people were very slow.   This was also when the seniority people had schedule changes. The people we needed the most were not there that day.  People that were just as fast as me or mildly faster. Edit: Or slower than me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere  No, I wanted to learn how to prevent this from happening again. I also want to understand why they keep slower workers, but are so quick to terminate new hires who are faster.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Makes sense, but I see their reason for not terminating the other people. Because they need them at least for now.

Comment: They did not terminate the slow ones because they are family or friends...

Comment: Some companies and departments have (or used to have) a policy of "last one in, first one out" when it came to cutting staff numbers. This sort of work has seasonal peaks and troughs and they may well have been looking to get rid of someone rather than specifically finding your work unacceptable.

Comment: @SolarMike: I missed the part in the question that identifies this. Please cite your references that qualify your statement.

Comment: Some amount of introspection and self-reflection is good when you've been terminated, but at the same time, it's possible that the real reasons you got fired have nothing to do with your actual performance. The fact is, there could a thousand and one reasons why you got terminated instead of someone else, and many of those potential reasons could have been completely out of your control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your words: you're open to learn more stuff and you are actively seeking advice to become better. You have tried your best and did everything you could to be helpful to your company.

If we're only looking at the numbers regarding the amount of boxes you have picked, it doesn't always meet the expected number, but I think you have provided enough reason why you're not always able to reach your target.

In my opinion the warehouse managers were not reasonable enough if they really fired you because you were not able to meet the 26 boxes. I don't think your termination could have been prevented. My advice is to continue to have a positive can-do attitude that leaves you open to learning more and always doing your best.

Wish you better luck with your next job!